# Should I encrypt Long-lived Facebook Access Token when storing them in my DB?

Tags: encryption, databases, facebook

I own an application that grabs some Long-Lived Facebook Access token, in order to be use later according to the corresponding logged user.

Should I need to encrypt them before storing them, to avoid any leaks if database is hacked, or a Facebook mechanism already exists to prevent some malicious usage?

Answer (score 4):

Simply: yes, encrypt it. And don't store the encryption key in the database.

The token is tied to your app, so an attacker might not be able to use it alone, but if they can breach your database and get your app secret too they can use the token. You'd have to encrypt the app secret and the user tokens.

Comment: I can't hide my app secret since I use the Javascript Facebook SDK in order to grab the short-lived facebook access token (that I migrate to long-lived on server side), and we know that Javascript isn't a confidential client. Thus, I really should encrypt the token, do you know a typical workflow to do it? Otherwise, I will study the case on the web :) Thanks a lot :)